# What’s wrong with my ternary expression or mapping in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, ternary

I need to retrieve a list (lets call it `list1`) of the double of every element smaller than 5 and put them in another list (let’s call it `list2`). I tried to use map as below but for some reason I get invalid syntax:

```
list2 = map(lambda x: x*2 if x < 5, list1)
```

I suspect it’s because the ternary expression needs an `else` condition. Is that it? And what should I do about it?

Comment: "ternary" literally means "3 parts"

Comment: `list2 = map(lambda x: x*2, filter(lambda x: x < 5, list1))`

Comment: That’s a really inefficient way to go about doing this, furas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right about the ternary expression part. Python doesn't allow you to use the syntax: `var = <action> if <condition>` without `else` because, in the case where `<condition> == False`, `var` becomes unknown.

You don’t really need map, however, you could use list comprehensions because not only do they solve your problems, they’re more efficient than mapping:

```
list2 = [x*2 for x in list1 if x < 5]
```

Comment: Works well thanks. I wasn’t familiar with list comprehensions before.